# Developer not identified error when logging in Oracle Instantclient on Catalina

Tags: macos, catalina, php, oracle

I have the Oracle Instantclient installed (PHP needs it for the oci extension to work), the install directory is `/opt/instantclient_19_3` and every time I log in after a reboot I get the following error messages which read translate to

> libclntsh.dylib.18.1 cannot be opened because the developer can't be verified. 
>   libclntshcore.dylib.19.1 cannot be opened because the developer can't be verified

I had the same errors popup when using Terminal and Hyper but since I've allowed those apps full disk access everything works fine. Still, after logging in I get both error messages, so I assume something needs permissions but I can't figure it out. Any hints?

[image: libclntsh.dylib.18.1]

[image: libclntshcore.dylib.19.1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!

The solution is to open the *General* tab in security and wait for the libs to show up and allow them there.[image]

Answer (score 5):

This should do it!

System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Developer Tools

[image]

**White-listing one-by-one**

While launching your non-verified app keep your System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> General open.
You can whitelist executables and libraries along the way. They will pop up in the general tab.

**A signing tool**

https://github.com/mitchellh/gon

Comment: Hyper, VS Code and Terminal are listed and checked.

Comment: @mazedlx Are they listen under Developer Tools?

Comment: Yes, they all are.

Comment: @mazedlx I have updated my answer. Whitelist one-by-one

Comment: The error only shows up after login. And all the „usual suspects“ are showing up in Developer Tools.

Comment: I don't see the "Developer Tools" category in the Privacy settings ?